# How to clean brake fluid spillage from vehicle floor?

Tags: brake-fluid

I had a leak out of my clutch master cylinder for quite a long time (until I figured what it was causing it).  The floor mat is pretty soaked in brake fluid (and I am replacing it) but there are also some on the floor.

What can I use to clean it, at least to some extent?  Regular dish soap and water?

Answer (score 3):

Someone else might have something better, but I'd probably just use a portable carpet cleaner with regular solution which goes in it. It should leach most or all of the brake fluid out of the carpet ... I doubt you'll get *all* of it out, but it shouldn't be too big of a deal. Clean it a couple of times and you should be golden. If you don't have the equipment, take it to a car detail shop, tell them what you want, and have them do it. They'll have techniques and equipment to get it out without an issue.

## Edit

*Note:Brake fluid is water soluble so you don't need special cleaners such as a de-greaser.  A wet vac with soap and water is suitable to resolve the issue.